# flex <mx:Array> bindable

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a very simple doubt. I have declared an array using `<mx:Array> ... </mx:Array>` with objects in it. Now If I have to make it bindable the how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can you make it [Bindable] ? or how to bind to the objects in the array?

Comment: I am able to bind the object in array but not able to make the Array [Bindable]. Hence not able to see the changes made in the Object.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to use an Array in this case.

Even an array that is designated as "Bindable" will not throw an update event if any of its items are changed or added. This means that if you have an array specified as the dataprovider for some component (combobox, datagrid, etc.), then the component will not change if you update the source array.

You want to instead use an ArrayCollection, which you can think of as an "array with binding" in this case. You always want to use ArrayCollection over array when assigning a dataprovider.

Answer (score 0):

Per the live docs:

Note: When defining a data binding expression that uses an array as the source of a data binding expression, the array should be of type ArrayCollection because the ArrayCollection class dispatches an event when the array or the array elements change to trigger data binding. For example, a call to ArrayCollection.addItem(), ArrayCollection.addItemAt(), ArrayCollection.removeItem(), and ArrayCollection.removeItemAt() all trigger data binding.

source:[LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_4.html)

So you would probably not want to bind to an array anyway. So assuming you make the change to array collection as recommended you will want to look at the  tag, I'm not even sure if this tag is current or not but it used to handle what you are wanting to do. Personally if you're hard-coding your AC like this anyway it should be just as easy to do it in actionScript and easier to set the binding.

Comment: Array
 <mx:Array id="mainMenuArray">
  <mx:Object name="{objName}" id="seperateWin" label="menuLabel" enabled ="{flag}" />
  <mx:Object name="closeSMS" id="closeSMS" label="test" />  
 </mx:Array>
I have a Bindable property flag when it gets changed the mainmenu array shud enable/disable the item.

pls help
got stuck